# objective c ou swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Olá, estou começando agora a programar para ios, eu ja sou programador java android, e queria saber no momento qual melhor para desenvolver aplicações para apple (iphone/tablet)
e vi que a apple lançou uma nova linguagem, por qual começar?

Comment: Aqui não é um bom lugar para esta pergunta, War Lock. O formato do StackOverflow não é ideal para discutir "qual a melhor opção" em um contexto tão amplo.

Comment: Vou dar uma opnião que acho que faz sentido. A linguagem Swift é muito mais expressiva que Objective-C e muito mais produtiva. Além disso qualquer código ou projeto Objective-C pode ser usado em conjunto com um projeto escrito em Swift permitindo reuso de código já escrito (e testado) em Objective-C. Desta forma a resposta é clara: Use Swift para novos projetos iOS ou OSX.